# How I can get all employee from Quickbooks with PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am trying to get all employee from Quickbook desktop using consoliBYTE PHP libray, but it generate error with "0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

```
$attr_iteratorID = '';
$attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';

if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
{
    // This is the first request in a new batch
    $last = $this->_quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
    $this->_quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);            

    // Set the current run to $last
    $this->_quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
}
else
{
    // This is a continuation of a batch
    $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
    $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';

    $last = $this->_quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
}

// Build the request
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
            <EmployeeQueryRq metaData="ENUMTYPE" requestID="' . $requestID . '">
            </EmployeeQueryRq>  
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
```

If i remove iterator from XML then it works fine and i get a new issue that i cannot get all employees and it displays error with invalid ResponsXML error
"QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed".

```
$Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
//$this->db->insert('save_response', $arr);
if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
{
    $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
    $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/EmployeeQueryRs');

    foreach ($List->children() as $Customer)
    {
        $arr = array(
            'listid' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet ListID'),
            'timecreated' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet TimeCreated'),
            'timemodified' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet TimeModified'),
            'editsequence' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet EditSequence'),
            'name' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet Name'),
            'isactive' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet IsActive'),
            'salutation' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet salutation'),
            'firstname' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet FirstName'),
            'middlename' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet MiddleName'),
            'lastname' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet LastName'),
            'employeeaddress' =>$Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet EmployeeAddress Addr1'),
            'city' =>$Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet EmployeeAddress City'),
            'state' =>$Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet EmployeeAddress State'),
            'postalcode' =>$Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet EmployeeAddress PostalCode'),
            'employeetype' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet EmployeeType'),
            'birthdate' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet BirthDate'),
            'hireddate' => $Customer->getChildDataAt('EmployeeRet HiredDate'),
            );

        QuickBooks_Utilities::log(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, 'Importing employee ' . $arr['name'] . ': ' . print_r($arr, true));



      $result = $this->db->insert('quickbook_employee', $arr);

    }
}

return true;
```

Can anybody let me know where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the documentation:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

You'll note that `EmployeeQuery` does not support iterators. So, remove the iterator.

This error:

`QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed`

99.9% of the time means you have a PHP or SQL error in your code. Specifically, in your response handler function.

Unfortunately, you didn't post enough code to where we actually have something we can test with, so no one is going to be able to tell you what the actual error is.

Did you check your PHP error log?

Comment: Yeah I have checked php log, but no error is there. and i have confirmed with php or sql error, but no error found as well :)

Comment: Then you need to post the rest of your code, and make sure your PHP error log is actually working.